# IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.1 can not resolve all Gradle classes

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, resolve

I created Gradle project with IntelliJ 13.0.1 and after

```
gradle cleanIdea Idea
```

starts to appear errors in my code. But when I start tasks everything works fine. So why IntelliJ can not find for example this org.gradle.api.file.FileTree? How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using IntelliJ's Gradle import is an *alternative* to generating IntelliJ files with `gradle idea`. They are not supposed to be used together.

Comment: I don't understand what are the things that are not supposed to be used together. Can you explain in pore details.

Comment: When using IntelliJ's Gradle import, you should never run `gradle idea`.

Comment: Ok. But when I am using sources and for them I want to create InteliJ Gradle Projct. How to do this without gradle idea command?

Comment: To create an IntelliJ project, use File->Import Project.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone: I had the same problem, but in my case the reason was that the GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable was not set. I was using the default Gradle wrapper, which uses this variable to locate the Gradle libraries. Strangely, the build itself worked fine - the problems were only in the editor window, and when trying to open Gradle sources.

In short, make sure GRADLE_USER_HOME correctly points to your user's *.gradle* directory (not the one in your project).